# How to run Job when Pipeline was triggered manually

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I setup jobs to run only when pushing/merging to branch "dev", but I also want it so I'm able to run them if I trigger that pipeline manually. Something like this:

```
test:
  stage: test
  <this step should be run always>

build:
  stage: build
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "dev"
    - if: <also run if the pipeline was run manually, but skip if it was triggered by something else>
```

This job is defined in a child "trigger" pipeline. This is how the parent looks like:

```
include:
  - template: 'Workflows/MergeRequest-Pipelines.gitlab-ci.yml'

stages:
  - triggers

microservice_a:
  stage: triggers
  trigger:
    include: microservice_a/.gitlab-ci.microservice_a.yml
    strategy: depend
  rules:
    - changes:
        - microservice_a/*
```

The effect I want to achieve is:

- Run `test` in all cases
- Run `build` in the child pipeline only when pushing/merging to "dev"
- Also run the `build` job when the pipeline is run maually
- Do not run the `build` job on any other cases (like a MR)

Answer (score 1):

The [rules examples](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#rules-examples) showcase:

```yaml
job:
  script: echo "Hello, Rules!"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: manual
      allow_failure: true
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"'
```

The [`when:manual`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#create-a-job-that-must-be-run-manually) should be enough in your case: it does require that a job doesn’t run unless a user starts it.

---

> Bonus question: This job is defined in a child "trigger" pipeline

Then it is related to [`gitlab-org/gitlab` issue 201938](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/201938), which is supposed to be fixed with GitLab 13.5 (Oct. 2020), but that only allow manual actions for parent-child pipeline (illustrated by [this thread](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/when-manual-in-downstream-pipeline-causes-upstream-to-report-failure/40862))

Double-check the [environment variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#list-all-environment-variables) as set in your child job

```
echo $CI_JOB_MANUAL
```

If true, that would indicate a job part of a manual triggered job.

While issue [22448 ("`$CI_JOB_MANUAL` should be set in all dependent jobs")](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/22448) points to this option *not* working, it includes a workaround.

Comment: Tried that, but the pipeline gets rejected with `Pipeline filtered out by workflow rules.` when run from the web interface

Comment: @arielnmz OK. I have edited the answer accordingly. What version of GitLab are you using? (if you are using a private on-premise GitLab, that is)

Comment: I'm using the "public" version, so it must be latest, I guess? Also, I might be misunderstaing but if I add `when` to the "parent" job, it gets skipped on pushes to the MR but still gets "filtered out" when run manually. I'm going to add how the parent looks like

Comment: @arielnmz OK so the use of "manual actions for parent-child pipelines" is not your use case then.

Comment: @arielnmz I have edited the answer to include a possible option for you to check.

Comment: I also updated the question to expand on the fact that this is a child pipeline, since I feel like that is the part that is complicating things. Btw, if that variable were true, where should I add the check for it? in the parent job or in the child job?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242946/discussion-between-vonc-and-arielnmz).